# Permit only specific HTTP operations in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring security config with a standard (?) filter chain configuration to allow some open endpoints of my api:

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests() {
            it.antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            it.antMatchers("/info").permitAll()
        }
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))

    return http.build()
}
```

This works fine. However I am currently trying to allow only GET operations on "/info". Is this somehow achievable in this config?

I tried `permitAll()` and `@PreAuthorize("SOME_ROLE")` in the Controller. This is results in an `AccessDeniedException` which is mapped to a HTTP 403 forbidden response which I do not want in this specific case. Not providing auth information to a protected API should result in a HTTP 401 response. I also could just define another path for the POST request, but this seems a bit clunky.

Comment: Now if only you could specify `antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/info")`. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.7.x/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.html#antMatchers(org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,java.lang.String...)).

Answer (score 0):

as M. Deinum posted in the comments the HTTPMethod can easily be specified in the antMatcher.

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests() {
            it.antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            it.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/info")
    }
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))

    return http.build()
}
```